# How do I enumerate the content of a zipped folder in Java?

Tags: java, zip

```
ZipeFile file = new ZipFile(filename);
ZipEntry folder = this.file.getEntry("some/path/in/zip/");
if (folder == null || !folder.isDirectory())
  throw new Exception();

// now, how do I enumerate the contents of the zipped folder?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't look like there's a way to enumerate `ZipEntry` under a certain directory.

You'd have to go through all [`ZipFile.entries()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries()) and filter the ones you want based on the [`ZipEntry.getName()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getName()) and see if it [`String.startsWith(String prefix)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String specificPath = "some/path/in/zip/";

ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
    ZipEntry ze = entries.nextElement();
    if (ze.getName().startsWith(specificPath)) {
        System.out.println(ze);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't - at least, not directly. ZIP files are not actually hierarchical. Enumerate all the entries (via ZipFile.entries() or ZipInputStream.getNextEntry()) and determine which are within the folder you want by examining the name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use `entries()`?  [API link](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html#entries())